# pass different variables in bootstrap modal

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

i am fetching few results from mysql db where each result has link ,on clicking that link a bootstrap modal should open.

So,everytime modal should shows content related to selected result.
My problem is its only taking 1st variable of loop.

**My code is:**

```
<?php

  $id = 1;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $title = $row['content_title'];
    $description = $row['content_description'];
    $content_url = $row['content_url'];
    $icon_url = $row['thumb_icon_url'];
    $id++;
    $_SESSION['result'][$id] = array('content_title' => $title, 'content_description' => $description, 'content_url' => $content_url, 'thumb_icon' => $icon_url);
    ?>
    <?php include 'templates/div_data.php'; ?>
  <?php
  }
}
?>
```

**div_data.php**

```
  <div class="col-md-3 photo-grid " style="float:left">
    <div class="well well-sm"  target="_blank">
      <figure>
        <img class="img" alt="PDF" src="<?php echo $icon_url; ?>" >
        <figcaption id="hide"> <p> <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Preview</a></p></figcaption>
      </figure>
      <a href="final.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&name=<?php echo $title; ?>" target="_blank">
        <h4><small><?php echo $title; ?></small></h4>
      </a>
      <br>
      <ul style="list-style: none;" class="container-fluid">
        <li class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 pull-left" id="hide"><a href="#" class="btn btn-x1" id="btnFilter" target="_blank" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Preview</a></li>
        <li name="id" class="col-md-6 col-xs-6"><a href="final.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&name=<?php echo $title; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnFilter" target="_blank">  View Full Doc</a></li>
        <li class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"> 100</i></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a data-toggle="modal" class="pull-right" data-target="#myModal"></a>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Preview</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form action="final.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&name=<?php echo $title; ?>"   class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" >
              <iframe id="iframe" class="embed-responsive-item item"src="web/viewer.html?file=https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/<?php echo $content_url; ?> &embedded=true#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
            </div>
            <h3 class="full col-md-3"><?php echo $title; ?></h3> 
            <hr>  <br>
            <p class="col-md-4">Description:</p>
            <p class="col-md-4"><?php echo $_SESSION['result'][$id]['content_description']; ?>
            </p>
            <p class="col-md-2">Shared by: Sarthak tuteja</p>
            <p class="col-md-2">Views:200000</p>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <button type="submit" id="btnFilter" formtarget="_blank" class="btn btn-primary " >View Full Doc</button>
            </div>                    
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: What does "its only taking 1st variable of loop." mean? It diesplays only `$title`? Or does it display all variables from the first iteration and then the looping end?

Comment: What's the point in opening and closing the ```<?php tags``` when using include? Its all in php anyway. Also having an include inside a loop has significant performance overhead. You could include the ```div_data.php``` file once and have the loop inside there for all the data

Comment: You need to change the modal body content form `javscript`. Can you share your `javascript` code?

Comment: @Nordenheim Twitter bootstrap modal with remote data shows same content everytime

Comment: Did you also notice that your `$_SESSION['result'][]` starts at `$_SESSION['result'][2]` Not that I think that is a big problem,

Comment: But, you don't have setup your modal to load from remote.

Comment: Without the javascript code this question is unanswerable. VTC in 5 minutes if it does not improve

Comment: @RiggsFolly its bootstrap modal,so all classes doing work